# XSL/XPath - search differently named elements (wildcard?)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wildcard

I've an address list in XML format, with multiple 'EstablishmentDetails' Using XSL I wish to transform it into a geojson file.

```
 <EstablishmentCollection>
    <EstablishmentDetail>
        <BusinessName>Company Name</BusinessName>
        <BusinessType>Retail</BusinessType>
        <AddressLine1>14 Somerset Place</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>London</AddressLine2>
        <AddressLine3>...</AddressLine3>
        <AddressLine4>...</AddressLine4>
        <PostCode>SW11 1AP</PostCode>
    </EstablishmentDetail>
</EstablishmentCollection>
```

I want to return all occurances of Business type 'Retail' in London. If London is in 'AddressLine2' It works using this line:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//EstablishmentDetail[BusinessType = 'Retail' and AddressLine2 = 'London']">
```

However, depending on the format of the address, London can occur in either AddressLine2, 3 or 4 (but never in multiple lines).
How do I search those three nodes? Is it pssible using with wildcards? Upon a Stackoverflow search I came upon:

```
*[starts-with(name(), 'London')]
```

But I'm unsure how to combine it with the working line above.

I'm using Saxon,XPath 2 if that helps.

Thanks

Comment: Your sample misses the final closing tag.

Comment: Thanks @Markus. Now included in <code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `//EstablishmentDetail[BusinessType = 'Retail' and 'London' = (AddressLine2, AddressLine3, AddressLine4)]` to select those `EstablishmentDetail` elements with the `Retail` `BusinessType` where at least one of the listed `AddressLineX` elements is `London`.

As an alternative you can use `//EstablishmentDetail[BusinessType = 'Retail' and *[matches(local-name(), 'AddressLine[234]')] = 'London']`.

Comment: After adding '= Retail' to the second option both worked as required. Thanks. Lots to read up on. I'm a bit unsure about `AddressLine[234]` though. What should I search for to learn it? 
I added an up vote, but as a newbie it doesn't display, which seems a shame & counter productive.

Comment: The `matches` function takes a regular expression and in a regular expression `[234]` matches any of the characters listed in the square brackets. https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#regex-syntax

Answer (score 0):

The following XPath 1.0 expression:

```
//EstablishmentDetail[node()[starts-with(name(), 'AddressLine') and starts-with(., 'London')] and BusinessType = 'Retail']
```

will select all nodes `EstablishmentDetail` where any address line starts with 'London' and the business type is 'Retail'.

If you want only to check `AddressLine2`  to `AddressLine4` only you need to limit the check to these fields, e.g. by using

```
//EstablishmentDetail[node()[(name() = 'AddressLine2' or name() = 'AddressLine3' or name() = 'AddressLine4') and starts-with(., 'London')] and BusinessType = 'Retail']
```

I don't known if XPath 2.0 will make life easier or not.

Comment: Thanks @Markus, it almost works as I want. i need it to return values with "London" only as some address lines start with "London Road". I've tried tinkering but can't correctly amend the `starts-with(., 'London')` to suit.

Comment: @DaveF use `. = 'London'` instead. But see Martin's answer for a better solution. (XPath 2.0 only I think.)

Comment: Thanks (Why does a comment have to be 16 characters, Why can't I just type 'Thanks'?)